# Manim: How to update function with defined time interval

Tags: python, animation, drawing, fft, manim

I am currently learning manim and I am trying to replicate 3b1b's fourier drawing animations. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qgreAUpPwM)
I've got everything set up and the basics of the animation is working. The only problem I've got is, that it doesnt draw the wanted figure. I am currently using valuetracker to update the function. To get the animation right, I think i need to have a constant "dt" between each updating, but I don't know how to implement that. I am not sure if valuetracker is the right way to do it. I've tried the using "dt" like in Theorem of Beethoven tutotial 8.3 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6qT8YZQeOw&t=506s). Wasn't able to make it work like that though.

Here is the code that updates all mobjects in the animation:

```
    def update_fct(c):  # Updating mobject
        for k in range(len(c)):
            c[k].become(c[k].start)
            for j in range(k):  # nth Circles rotates around all circles before
                c[k].rotate(TAU * values[j, 2] * alpha.get_value(), about_point=c[j].get_center())

            dots[k].move_to(circles[k].points[0])  # move dots to new position

            if k == N - 1:  # Only track path of last dot
                old_path = paths[k].copy()
                old_path.append_vectorized_mobject(Line(old_path.points[-1], dots[k].get_center()))
                old_path.make_smooth()
                paths[k].become(old_path)

            lines[k].put_start_and_end_on(circles[k].get_center(), dots[k].get_center())  # Update Arrow

    circles.add_updater(update_fct)

    self.add(circles,lines,paths[N-1])  # Only add circles, arrows and last path
    self.play(
        alpha.set_value, 1,
        rate_func=linear,
        run_time=10
    )
    circles.clear_updaters()
```

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/master/from_3b1b/active/diffyq/part2/fourier_series.py#L5) is the original source code.

Comment: @TheoremOfBeethoven Thanks !